# Using different versions of PHP with virtual domains/hosts

Tags: php, virtualhost

I'm hosting several websites in a single directory, using Apache virtualHosts. Some of them need PHP 5.2 and others are fine with PHP 5.3. How can I specify which directories use each version and how do I use multiple versions of PHP on one system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would have to run PHP in CGI mode versus as a module for Apache (or atleast the 2nd, 3rd, ..., nth versions).

Here's a fantastic how-to I found on the web for it:

http://gggeek.altervista.org/2007/07/21/running-multiple-php-versions-on-a-single-apache-install/